# Installing Shapely with GEOS on heroku

Tags: installation, shapely, geos

I have a web mapping app running on Heroku.  My app is written in python.  Using pip I was able to install various pure python libraries that were needed.  I would now like to install Shapely too.

This is simple enough (with pip) but how do I install the geos pre-requisite within the virtualenv (venv) directory?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Haven't tried, but found [a tweet that looks promising](https://mobile.twitter.com/JCSanford/status/281540051203141632) and leads to [a repo even more promising](https://github.com/JasonSanford/heroku-buildpack-python-geos).

Seems like the concept of "buildpack" is a way to get things loaded on Heroku, and someone has made GEOS iavailable as a buildpack. By setting a custom geos-path you can install Shapely via pip and it will find GEOS.

Answer (score 4):

Heroku now has built-in, **experimental** support for a few geo-location libraries including shapely's dependency GEOS.

You just need to set the following config variable from your command line:

```
heroku config:set BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES=1
```

You can find out more [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-c-deps)

Answer (score 1):

You also install them using pip. You'll have to specify a `requirements.txt` file though. It's basically just a text file where you list the Python libraries you want to install. Just put the text file on the root of your repository. Once it's there, you can just run pip like so:

```
$pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Here's an example `requirements.tx`t file

```
Shapely==1.2.17
Flask==0.8
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
certifi==0.0.8
chardet==1.0.1
distribute==0.6.24
gunicorn==0.14.2
requests==0.11.
```

You can read more about it on the [Heroku help page](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip).

Answer (score 0):

You can install geos as a vendored binary on Heroku. This blog post that I wrote details how to do it:

http://www.saintsjd.com/2014/05/12/run-vendored-binaries-on-heroku.html